# How can I tell my android Xamarin compiler to use the nuget packages in their correct filepaths?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I am just having a problem with Xamarin an nuget seemingly not installing to the right folder with [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/) example code here.

No matter what I do, nuget installs to the local solution/package folder (and even then only makes a few .dll files and nothing more), but when I try to build it the compiler always searches the packages in AppData\Local\Xamarin and therefore is unable to find them.

How can I tell it to look elsewhere or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself, so here is it:

It apparently came from me messing around in the Xamarin folder, so what I did was remove the bin/obj/package folders from all my affected projects and then removed the entire contents of my Xamarin folder.

After reinstalling the Android SDK through the Xamarin installer and then manually reinstalling the SDKs I need through the Visual Studio Android SDK manager I simply rebuilt the project after setting NuGet to autorestore packages and then after it downloaded and built everything I resolved the last error by adding a reference to a specific .dll in the package folder of my project solution path (as the error message explained to me).

Then I rebuilt it again and deployed it. Everything works fine.

tl;dr if something goes wrong with your NuGet packages, go the easy way and just delete and reinstall the parts that don't work

Comment: @ uncanny, glad to know that you have resolved this issue, would you please mark your reply as the answer? So it would help other community members who met the same issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

When installing a NuGet package, it'll also add an entry in the `.csproj` file for the given project in which it was added to.

You can basically change the path of the NuGet package which is causing the issue to something like the following, depending on your project structure:

```
..\packages\<your.package>
```

Additionally, [with the release of NuGet 2.1](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior), you can add an entry in your `NuGet.Config` file which defines where you want your packages to be restored from:

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\[relative or absolute path]" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Again, if you do so, make sure that the path to the NuGet package in the `.csproj` is the same as the one defined in your `NuGet.Config` file.